# Organize :marks list?

Tags: mark

Is there a way to organize / parse the `:marks` list?  E.g. list them in the order they were created, rather than alphabetically.  Or see which marks are associated with currently open buffers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [getmarklist()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getmarklist%28%29) function to get information about the list of global or local marks.

Comment: getmarklist() doesn't return info about the creation-time of the mark, though. It basically returns what `:marks` returns AFAIK. So maybe not what the OP wants.

Comment: But the last part of this question *can* be achieved with `getmarklist()` and something like `filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')`.